# Trying to understand JS async/await

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-2017

I'm learning async/await and created a small fiddle @ https://jsfiddle.net/mpycio/rb8taLt7/.

```
const parse = async (num) => {
    let res = await new Promise(resolve => 
    setTimeout(() => {resolve(num * 2)}, 0)
  )
  
  return res
}

[1,2,3,4].forEach(async (num) => {
    log(`parsing:  ${num}`);
  const res = await parse(num);
  log(`parsing result: ${res}`);
})
```

I'm missing something as I was especting the logged results to be:

> parsing: 1
>
> parsing result: 2
>
> parsing: 2
>
> parsing result: 4 ...

So my question is how to correctly write the forEach loop to guarantee that result of a promise is resolved inside the loop?

Edit1: So this has already been answered before, solution is indeed **for of** loop: https://jsfiddle.net/mpycio/rb8taLt7/4/

Comment: what you want is to parse it synchronously, you don't need a async await function for this

Comment: @marvel308: I actually do need async/await, this is just an example but I have a parse function that will make a call to a database and I will need to wrap it in a promise.